# iPhone: Handle action event from webview page

Tags: iphone

I am loading a html page using loadHTMLString.

```
[myWebview loadHTMLString:myHtmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Its loading properly. In this html web page, i'm also adding buttons, drop down(with selection) etc. I want to catch the action events in my code now for these web page controls. For example, from the drop down if user chooses an option, i need to add another 'textarea' dynamically in the same web page. and, if user clicks on a button(button from the webview), i need to handle some events. I would like to know, how to do some tasks under the events triggered for controls in web view which is generated by my string.

Could someone please advise me.

Comment: you can handle the events on UIWebView using the java scripts on the webview

Answer (score 1):

to handle event on button in webview load a url in webview for ex:http://button1clicked and then in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method check if the url is button1clicked then return no and also perform your action which you want to do on button clicked.
for example:

write this in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

```
if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://button1clicked"])
{
    //perform you action you want to do
    return NO;
}
```

and on button click call javascript function `window.location='http://button1clicked';`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that UIWebView is not intended for Sub-Classing. However, you can still detect all the events.
But maybe this will help : [Tutorial](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/)